# How come there is "Integer Overflow and Underflow" in string variables in smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, string

I was analyzing a contract in [Oyente](https://github.com/enzymefinance/oyente#readme). The contract is :

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Test{
    address admin;

    function Test() public{
        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    string str = "";

    function setStr(string _str) public{
        str = _str;
    }

    function getStr() public view returns (string){
        return str;
    }
}
```

When I passed this contract to oyente to analyze then the following report came:

```
INFO:root:contract Test.sol:Test:

INFO:symExec:   ============ Results ===========

INFO:symExec:     EVM Code Coverage:             24.1%

INFO:symExec:     Integer Underflow:             True

INFO:symExec:     Integer Overflow:              True

INFO:symExec:     Parity Multisig Bug 2:         False

INFO:symExec:     Callstack Depth Attack Vulnerability:  False

INFO:symExec:     Transaction-Ordering Dependence (TOD): False

INFO:symExec:     Timestamp Dependency:          False

INFO:symExec:     Re-Entrancy Vulnerability:         False

INFO:symExec:Test.sol:16:9: Warning: Integer Underflow.

        return str

Integer Underflow occurs if:

    return str = 1

INFO:symExec:Test.sol:11:5: Warning: Integer Overflow.

    function setStr(string _str) public{

    ^

Spanning multiple lines.

Integer Overflow occurs if:

    _str = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639932

INFO:symExec:   ====== Analysis Completed ======
```

It shows Integer overflow and underflow in a string variable. I really don't understand how it could happen or how to solve it. Any help will be appreciated.